# how to assign output as an variable?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a PHP file sorting and displaying some data from an XML. I am using the result/output from the PHP file to use in the second to determine if open/closed based on the output.

**Example:**

```
Description: The page is closed due to maintenance.
Status: Closed
```

I get the `Description` from the first PHP file and then search for the word "closed" in the second to get the status.

**Question:**
Can I combine these two PHP files and still be able to separate the description? Now I am using:

```
<div class="zero-margin col-lg-8 col-md-7 col-sm-12">
 <span class="open">@include('status')</span>
</div>

<div class="row col-lg-11 col-md-11">
  <p class="info">@include('info')</p>
</div>
```

but this will not work if I have everything in the same file. Can I make the first section an variable and use that in the HTML file the user can see? How can I assign an variable to the output from line 1-40 as an example?

I am using laravel if that makes a difference.
Any help is greatly appreciated!
Please ask the question if something is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split a blade file in sections.

Say this is `a.blade.php`:

```php
@section('info')
The page is closed due to maintenance.
@endsection
@section('status')
Closed
@endsection
```

Then you can use `@yield`:

```php
@include('a')
<div class="zero-margin col-lg-8 col-md-7 col-sm-12">
 <span class="open">@yield('status')</span>
</div>

<div class="row col-lg-11 col-md-11">
  <p class="info">@yield('info')</p>
</div>
```

Comment: ^typo on `@include('a')`. I also have a question regarding just the `@include`. I am not able to `@include` my file. this includes the file above the `<div>`. It seems like `@include` pastes the whole file included where that `@include('a')` is? have I done anything wrong then?

Comment: Include does do that, but if you have the content in between `@section ... @endsection`  then the content is stored in a "section array" and you can choose to echo each section with a `@yield`